# Do I need a new certificate?

Tags: windows, ssl-certificate

We currently are running our server in a Windows 2008 R2 environment (IIS7) on the company intranet.

We are moving to a hosted server running W2012 on XAMP (apache/tomcat) stack.  Do I need to order a new cert or can I use the old one?

We are keeping the same domain name and I read that you should be able to use the old cert if domain name stays the same but it doesn't make sense to me since the server would have a different hostname/checksum.  What is the word here?

Comment: SSL certificates are not server-specific, and it's the hostname the user sees, not the hostname of the server that matters.

Comment: @ceejayoz - Geotrust informed me they needed the new server's CSR so in effect that is assigning me a new cert (reissuing is technically the same thing as a new cert right?).

Answer (score 1):

No, you won't need a new one. SSL (TLS) certificates are only composed of the private key and the public certificate.  Everything you need is in those two parts, whether they're separate files or combined.

Comment: So I am guessing I don't need to tell the signer that I am moving servers/IPs?

Comment: Nope, because they don't need that in the first place.

Comment: Geotrust said that I had to have the cert reissued which required a new CSR from new server - so there isn't really an easy way to just copy the cert over.  It is really in effect applying a new cert right?